Missing expression in Oracle Function
I have problem with PL SQL Function
FUNCTION isConditionsForChargeChanged(
                                      adj_date varchar2, 
                                      acc_num  varchar2
                                     ) RETURN integer IS
  res integer;
BEGIN
    SELECT CASE
             WHEN EXISTS
                 ( SELECT DISTINCT 1
                     FROM custhasproduct@rbm_dblink chp
                     JOIN custproductdetails@rbm_dblink cpd
                       ON chp.customer_ref = cpd.customer_ref
                      AND chp.product_seq = cpd.product_seq
                     JOIN custproducttariffdetails@rbm_dblink cptd
                       ON cptd.customer_ref = cpd.customer_ref
                      AND cptd.product_seq = cpd.product_seq
                     JOIN custproductstatus@rbm_dblink cps
                       ON cps.customer_ref = chp.customer_ref
                      AND cps.product_seq = chp.product_seq
                     JOIN tariff@rbm_dblink tr
                       ON tr.tariff_id = cptd.tariff_id
                      AND tr.catalogue_change_id in
                          (SELECT catalogue_change_id
                             FROM cataloguechange
                            where catalogue_status = 3)
                     JOIN custoverrideprice@rbm_dblink cop
                       ON cop.customer_ref = cpd.customer_ref
                      AND cop.product_seq = cpd.product_seq
                    WHERE cpd.account_num = acc_num
                      AND ((EXTRACT(month FROM cps.effective_dtm) =
                          EXTRACT(month FROM TO_DATE(adj_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')) AND
                          EXTRACT(year FROM cps.effective_dtm) =
                          EXTRACT(year FROM TO_DATE(adj_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')) AND
                          cps.product_status in ('SU', 'OK', 'TX')) /* Проверка изменения активности услуги в данном отчетном периоде */
                          OR (EXTRACT(month FROM cptd.start_dat) =
                          EXTRACT(month FROM TO_DATE(adj_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')) AND
                          EXTRACT(year FROM cptd.start_dat) =
                          EXTRACT(year FROM TO_DATE(adj_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')) AND
                          cptd.END_DAT IS NULL) /* Проверка на смену тарифа в данном отчетном периоде*/
                          OR (EXTRACT(month FROM cop.start_dat) =
                          EXTRACT(month FROM TO_DATE(adj_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')) AND
                          EXTRACT(year FROM cop.start_dat) =
                          EXTRACT(year FROM date
                                       TO_DATE(adj_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')) AND
                          COP.END_DAT IS NULL)) /* Проверка на переопределение цены в данном отчетном периоде */
                 ) THEN
              0
             ELSE
              1
           END
      INTO res
      FROM dual;

  RETURN res;
END isConditionsForChargeChanged;


Error message:
PL/SQL: ORA-00936: Missing expression Line 190 Pos 46
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored Line 181 Pos 3
Line 190 Pos 46 (mark with (?)):
...and ((extract (month from cps.effective_dtm) (?)= extract (month from to_date(adj_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD'))...

Line 181 Pos 3 (mark with (?)):
...(?)SELECT CASE when EXISTS (...

What could be the problem? I don't see any gross syntax violations.

I don't see any syntax error either. I'd try to reduce this query step by step and see when the error stops popping up. Maybe there is just some special character in the code that we don't see?

@BarbarosÖzhan When the OP's debugging is based on particular lines of their code the you should not reformat the code so that it does not match the formatting they are discussing as it may make the code more difficult to debug (and invalidate the second half of the question). I suggest that you rollback your edit and preserve the OP's original formatting.

As some of your columns containing dates are string columns, you can simplify the year/month comparisons by applying SUBSTR: TO_CHAR(cps.effective_dtm, 'YYYY-MM') = SUBSTR(adj_date, 1, 7).

This seems to be wrong:
AND EXTRACT (YEAR FROM cop.START_DAT) = EXTRACT (YEAR FROM DATE to_date ( adj_date , 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
                                                           ----

Remove DATE keyword (underlined in above piece of code), presuming that adj_date is a string in yyyy-mm-dd format which will then be converted to a valid date datatype value so that year can be extracted from it).

You can simplify your WHERE filter (and eliminate the excess date keyword at the same time):
WHERE cpd.account_num = acc_num
AND   (  (   TRUNC(TO_DATE(adj_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'MM') = TRUNC(cps.effective_dtm, 'MM')
         AND cps.product_status in ('SU', 'OK', 'TX')
         )
      OR (   TRUNC(TO_DATE(adj_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'MM') = TRUNC(cptd.start_dat, 'MM')
         AND cptd.END_DAT IS NULL
         )
      OR (   TRUNC(TO_DATE(adj_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'MM') = TRUNC(cop.start_dat, 'MM')
         AND COP.END_DAT IS NULL
         )
      )

Or, slightly more verbose but would allow you to use an index on your date columns:
WHERE cpd.account_num = acc_num
AND   (  (   TRUNC(TO_DATE(adj_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'MM') >= cps.effective_dtm
         AND cps.effective_dtm < ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(TO_DATE(adj_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'MM'), 1)
         AND cps.product_status in ('SU', 'OK', 'TX')
         )
      OR (   TRUNC(TO_DATE(adj_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'MM') >= cptd.start_dat
         AND cptd.start_dat < ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(TO_DATE(adj_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'MM'), 1)
         AND cptd.END_DAT IS NULL
         )
      OR (   TRUNC(TO_DATE(adj_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'MM') >= cop.start_dat
         AND cop.start_dat < ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(TO_DATE(adj_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'MM'), 1)
         AND COP.END_DAT IS NULL
         )
      )

